# Custom post type archive page blank

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, archives, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I created a CPT with slug `plist` via cutom plugin I made.

In my local host the archive work but in live server it return blank page.

Here is the 'include' archive page code

```
/**
 * Add Price List archive template
 * @since    1.0.0
*/
add_filter( 'archive_template', 'get_plist_archive_template' ) ;
function get_plist_archive_template( $archive_template ) {
     global $post;

     if ( is_post_type_archive ( 'plist' ) ) {
          $archive_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '\partials\archive-plist.php';
     }
     return $archive_template;
}
```

Link: http://cratetimer.com/plist/

Also this may help:

```
/**
 * Register Custom Post Type Price List
 * @since    1.0.0
*/
if ( ! function_exists('price_item_post_type') ) {
    add_action( 'init', 'price_item_post_type', 0 );
    // Register Custom Post Type
    function price_item_post_type() {

        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Price Lists', 'Post Type General Name', 'plist' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Price List', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'plist' ),
            'menu_name'             => __( 'Price List', 'plist' ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Price List', 'plist' ),
            'archives'              => __( 'Price List Archives', 'plist' ),
            'attributes'            => __( 'Price List Attributes', 'plist' ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Price List:', 'plist' ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Price Lists', 'plist' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Price List', 'plist' ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'plist' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Price List', 'plist' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Price List', 'plist' ),
            'update_item'           => __( 'Update Price List', 'plist' ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Price List', 'plist' ),
            'view_items'            => __( 'View Price Lists', 'plist' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search Price List', 'plist' ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'plist' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'plist' ),
            'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'plist' ),
            'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'plist' ),
            'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'plist' ),
            'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'plist' ),
            'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Price List', 'plist' ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Price List', 'plist' ),
            'items_list'            => __( 'Price Lists', 'plist' ),
            'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Price Lists navigation', 'plist' ),
            'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Price Lists', 'plist' ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'label'                 => __( 'Price List', 'plist' ),
            'description'           => __( 'Price list item for market', 'plist' ),
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'supports'              => array( ),
            'hierarchical'          => false,
            'public'                => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => true,
            'menu_position'         => 20,
            'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-tag',
            'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
            'can_export'            => true,
            'has_archive'           => true,        
            'exclude_from_search'   => true,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'capability_type'       => 'page',
        );
        register_post_type( 'plist', $args );

    }

}
```

I tried flush_rewrite_rules() and it didn't work.

Comment: Please instead of vote down my question, tell me what is wrong with it maybe I can improve it.

Comment: your archive template contains an archive template filter? The filter is applied before the template is loaded, that can’t possibly work.

Comment: If you mean `get_plist_archive_template`. This run outside the archive template `archive-plist.php`.

Comment: How I can correct my code?

Comment: Have you tried putting your archive file in direct theme folder and not using `archive_template` filter. Let WP choose archive page?

Comment: @AniruddhaGawade Yes, I tried this. It work this way. But I really want to know how to do this from inside a custom plugin.

Comment: In that case you'll have to debug `get_plist_archive_template`. Print `$archive_template` and see if it is taking roper value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell WP that archive.php should apply to your custom post type as well as it's other defaults. You can use [pre_get_posts filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to do this, be sure to research this well before using it as there is a right and wrong way to use this filter.

For example, try:

```
function add_custom_post_type_to_archiving( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'custom_post_type_name1','custom_post_type_name2'
        ));
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_archiving' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is working on your local machine and not on the server, I suspect that it is environment related. This causes me to suspect:

```
$archive_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '\partials\archive-plist.php';
```

If you are running this on a standard LAMP stack, it is likely that you should be using forward slashes (`/`) instead of backslashes (`\`).

Also, there is a chance that the `dirname()` call is returning a path with a slash at the end, which would mean that the path has a double slash in it ( likely `/\`).

I suggest trying to change the direction of your slashes, and then changing `dirname()` to [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/). You'll notice that `plugin_dir_path()` utilizes a function named [`trailingslashit()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/trailingslashit) which appends a trailing slash if there isn't one already. This means that you should remove the first slash in your path.

All together, it would look like this:

```
$archive_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'partials/archive-plist.php';
```